# Facing issue in GITLAB while reconfiguring

Tags: linux, database, gitlab

rails_migration[gitlab-rails] (gitlab::database_migrations line 51) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/resources/rails_migration.rb line 16) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Command execution failed. STDOUT/STDERR suppressed for sensitive resource

Comment: Getting the above error while reconfiguring Gitlab

Comment: Please share more details. Is this problem really related to programming?

Comment: No @Nico Haase,
its DB issue

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Whatever you mean by "DB issue", this looks off-topic to me

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
Gitlab-rake gitlab:background_migrations:finalize[ProjectNamespaces::BackfillProjectNamespaces,projects,id,'[null\,"up"]']

Gitlab-rake db:migrate

Gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```